# PHP - Get part of $_GET string

Tags: php, get

I currently have this:

```
$thispage = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if($thispage == "i=f" || $thispage == "i=f&p=t" ) echo "active";
```

Although, the "i=f&p=t" is not correct, as the page looks like this:

```
i=f&p=t&cid=71&id=161
```

My question is, how can I do so if just the first part of the $_GET string is correct (in this example "i=f&p=t) then it will match `$thispage`. I don't want it to check for `& $_GETs`

I want $thispage to work with other pages than just the example above. I only want to check the first part of the string. Not what comes after &

Comment: Why don't use the query string as the whole world do?

Comment: Why don't you use `$_GET`?!

Comment: Well, i= is index.php, and the letter that comes after is whatever page you are on. In this case "forum".
The cid and id changes from topic to topic, therefore I need some method that will see through this.

Comment: Because $_GET will just give me index.php no matter what page I'm on. Since index.php controls all other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $thispage);

if ( $thispage['i'] === 'f' OR ($thispage['i'] === 'f' AND $thispage['p'] === 't') ) {
    echo 'active';
}
```

**Update:**

> I don't want it to check for & $_GETs

I don't know why you don't want to use `$_GET` if it's the *Query String* that you're working on that now, but you can do the following as well, which makes more sense:

```
if ( $_GET['i'] === 'f' OR ($_GET['i'] === 'f' AND $_GET['p'] === 't') ) {
    echo 'active';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 'i=f') !== false) {
    echo "active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is truly what you want to do, then you are actually checking if

```
if (substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], 0, 7) === "i=f&p=t")
```

Comment: I want $thispage to work with other pages than just the example above. I only want to check the first part of the string. Not what comes after &

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? What do you mean by "work with"?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the url parameters directly by using the `$_GET` array.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

If you want to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` you can use the [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to parse the query string:

```
<?php
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

?>
```